# In Firebird stored procedure how do I insert non UTF text into a UTF field?

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

In my stored procedure I'm doing this;

```
declare variable my_text varchar(512);
...
select non_utf_notes from table1 where unique_field = :some_value
into :my_text;
....
insert into table2(unique_field, utf_text)
values(:some_value, :my_text);
```

Table1 has no character set defined, but table2 is defined with a character set of UTF8.

Comment: I changed the variable declaration to; declare variable my_text varchar(512) character set iso_8859_1; and that seems to solve the problem.

Comment: to help others you ought to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't explicitly set a default character set in your database (or the field in question was created before the default was set), then a (VAR)CHAR field has character set `NONE` unless you explicitly specified a character set for the field.

Character set `NONE` is a bit of an annoyance (although it can be powerful), as it is essentially binary data. The absence of a specific real character set means that upon conversion to a real character set, the bytes are handled in that character set. This is fine for most character sets (although you might get the wrong characters), but UTF-8 has a variable length encoding where certain combinations of bytes are invalid.

To handle conversion from `NONE` to `UTF8`, you either need to be sure that the data in `NONE` is really UTF-8, or you first need to cast to the 'right' character set (eg `WIN1252`) before casting to `UTF8` as this will perform the right encoding.